# Calculate mean absolute error (MAE) of two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays and would like to calculate the mean absolute error:

[image]

Is my implementation correct?

```
Data = nib.load(File).get_fdata()
data = nib.load(file).get_fdata()

mae = np.mean(np.abs(Data - data))
```

Comment: Looks correct! Are you facing any issues with this?

Comment: This function is also implemented in scitkit-learn, if you didn't want to write it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. No error comes when I calculate MAE with my implementation. But "no error" does not yet mean that the result is correct :)

I have seen the implementation in scitkit-learn. But I get the error "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. None expected <= 2"

Comment: You can make it slightly shorter and faster (by a miniscule amount unless you call it really often), by writing `abs(Data - data).mean()`. Don't use the `np.*` functions if not necessary

Comment: Thanks :) I see it for the first time in such contexts that there is no "np." prefix.

Comment: TBH it is quite hard to predict which functions are available as [`ndarray` methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) but since they don't have to sanitize their inputs like the free-standing functions (since you could call `np.mean` with a plain python `list` but not the method), they tend to be a bit faster. Similarly, the builtin `abs` function quickly dispatches to `ndarray.__abs__()` with the same effect. Just don't rely on those if you don't know that the input is a proper numpy array